# Кириллицу json парсить в айфон

Tags: objective-c, json

Здравствуйте.

JSON дает строку типа `{"id":5,"name":"\u041b\u044e\u0431\u0438\u043c\u043e\u0439"}`, затем я парсю ее в массив `arrayOfNames`:

```
arrayOfNames = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

а когда вывожу в cell.textLabel.text, выходит ошибка:

> `[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9323ce0
> 2013-02-21 17:24:57.039 Floral[2326:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9323ce0'`

Как конвертировать строку "`\u041b\u044e\u0431\u0438\u043c\u043e\u0439`" в нормальный вид?

Answer (score 3):

А где вы видите массив? У вас словарь, вот оно в словарь и сконвертило.

Answer (score 1):

NSJSONSerialization парсит в словарь. значения берутся по значению ключа:

```
[arrayOfNames valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: делаю NSLog(@"%@", arrayOfNames); выводит:
10 =     {
        id = 5;
        name = "\U041b\U044e\U0431\U0438\U043c\U043e\U0439";
    };

делаю NSLog(@"%@", [arrayOfNames valueForKey:@"name"]); выводит (null)

Comment: как arrayOfNames описан?

Comment: NSArray *arrayOfNames; //